# Tkinter gui class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to build a basic system controller GUI class with tkinter. Such a class that I need to instantiate within a loop, where I also want make use of the loop index in order to create a text in the layout. 
This gui will include a Text at the top, 1 vertical radio Button with 2 options and 1 vertical radio button with 5 options which will be normally invisible and will be invoked according to the outcome of the first button.
As I am planning to create the same frame multiple times, I am struggling at managing the layout.

I am not looking for a complete solution. As I am new at tkinter, I need a solid starting point which I can go further develop by myself.
How should I structure my class ? 
This is what I have done up to now :

```
import Tkinter as tk
import json
with open('config.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)

class gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.zone = zone
        self.node = node 
        self.id = self.zone, self.node
```

Here when I am instantiating my class I would like to pass zone, node.

```
for zone, node in data["ID"].iteritems():
    for node in node:
         app = gui(zone, node)
```

Comment: Starting point: `import tkinter`. More seriously: What is your current problem? Creating the options in the loop, or the layout, or packing it all into a reusable class, or what? What do you have so far?

Comment: I was not able to find clear and  easy examples of it. There are couple different approaches even when defining a class

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed if you don't improve it. Please read the [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) topics in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a beginner and you don't look for a complete solution, I take it that you're looking for good information sources about Tkinter.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk

This is where I started learning about Tkinter myself and can recommend it to everyone else. This should teach you all the basic information that you need to know when it comes to Tkinter and if after finishing the playlist you want to learn more, there's a follow up playlist by the same guy for those who are familiar with the basics.

If you're looking for some information about something specific in Tkinter module or it's widgets, you can find it here:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

You can find a lot of info about any specific widget you'd like to use there.

Edit:
Last but not least there is always (not so beginner friendly but most informative) Tkinter documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

Comment: thx for the advice. However, I didnt find http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ very useful, instead I will watch the tutorials

Comment: Glad I could help, http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ might be more useful when you're not sure about one specific widget or how to use it.